# Rails: retrieve data from multiple tables without association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a trip model and every trip has_many Flight, Lodging, CarRental, Activity etc. Every model has its own fields, but all of them have a "start date" and/or "end date". I want to create a dashboard and show an itinerary.

What is the best solution to query the database and have a result like:

```
Row    Model    Id    Date        Type
#1     Flight   2     2014-12-01  Flight
#2     Lodging  54    2014-12-02  Check-in
#3     Lodging  54    2014-12-08  Check-out
#4     Flight   3     2014-12-10  Flight
```

I would like to get this result and create an itinerary like:

```
result.each do |itinerary_item|
    item = @trip.send(itinerary_item.Model).find(itinerary_item.id)
    ** do things with the item in a view model
end
```

But the way I am thinking does not seem smart. I have to ORDER the itinerary dates!

EDIT 1:
I am trying to do something like:

```
@trip = Trip.find(1)
itinerary = {}
itinerary['items'] = []
@trip.flights.each do |flight|
   itinerary['items'] << [flight.class.name, flight.id, flight.departure_date]
end
@trip.lodging.each do |ld|
   itinerary['items'] << [ld.class.name, ld.id, ld.check_in_date]
   itinerary['items'] << [ld.class.name, ld.id, ld.check_out_date]
end
... and so on with all the related models. and then
result = itinerary['items'].sort_by {|c, i, date| date }
... and then
result.each do |item|
    ... do the magic querying the database again =(
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach is to add a method in your `Trip` model that returns all the trip's parts.

Something **like** this:

```
def parts
  (flights + lodgings + rentals + activities).to_a
end
```

and then in your view iterate over this `parts` array:

```
@trip.parts.each do |part|
  # your code here
end
```

**UPDATE:**

In that case, you can create a hash that has all the information you want for every part:

```
def parts
  flights_info = flights.map { |flight| { :model => "Flight", :id => flight.id, :date => flight.date, :type => "flight" } }
  lodgings_info = lodgings.map { |lodging| { :model => "Lodging, :id => lodging.id, :date => lodging.date, :type => lodging.type } }
  ...
  items = (flights_info + lodgings_info + ...).to_a
  items.sort_by { |item| item[:date] }.reverse
end
```

and then use it in your view like this: `@trip.parts.each { |part| part[:model] }`. Please keep in mind this a very simple approach to get you moving, you'll definitely need to rethink its architecture later.

Comment: Hello @sebkomianos! Thanks for your answer. But how would I sort dates between parts then? I was not clear the first time, sorry. I have edited my question!

Comment: Thank you so much. Any help on how to "rethink" this architecture?

Comment: @Guido Anytime! :) The "rethink" depends on what exactly you want and how you can see this evolving. For example, maybe you want to create another model called `Itinerary` that `belongs to` `Trip`, gets updated everytime something is added to a trip and handles all this particular logic.

*(by the way, if you are building a traveling/holidays/etc application and need any testers I would love to help)*

Comment: Hey @sebkomianos! Thank you! Your answer was exactly what I was thinking yesterday while showering haha I have just started my application and have been learning rails for the past year (it is hard for someone with a Law degree hehe). My project is a travelling app for brazilians who have never travelled abroad. So basically I am giving a step-by-step guide on how to plan everything. And then, based on their interaction with the site, update tips and infos regarding "what's next".

Comment: For example, there is no need to show them how to get the best plane ticket if they have already purchased the ticket, so instead I will show them how to get to the airport, to understand airport signs in other languages etc... My plan is to finish the site before 2015 hehe Thanks anyway and I will remember to contact you!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I am not particularly super experienced either, although I come from a Computer Science degree I've only started playing with Rails seriously in the past two years. Keep it up! :)